# Fragment Error : incompatible types,required android.app.fragment but found activity.messagefragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
 @Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessageFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

the error printed is:

```
incompatible types,required android.app.fragment but found activity.messagefragment
```

Answer (score 24):

In your `messagefragment` class you need to import

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Instead of

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: This is correct, if OP wants to avoid `required android.app.Fragment` error message, it is necessary to replace `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `android.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 5):

Your `Activity` must extend from `AppCompatActivity`, then you call your fragment using `getSupportFragmentManager`, that should do it.

It'll go like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, TabFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have probably included the wrong class, check your import statements.

You should have this in there:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check imports of **all** the fragment java classes and make sure that they all have

`import android.app.Fragment;`

Instead of

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

**It solves.**

Answer (score 0):

Check both the imports of both fragment and view have to be same `android.app.fragment`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object of `android.app.Fragment` class, but you are not returning `android.app.Fragment` as in case 2, which is `MessageFragment()`. You should extend `android.app.Fragment` in `MessageFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

go to the tab.class which u have problem in and change import android.app.Fragment; to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

it will run .

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in two ways.

1 -In your messagefragment class you need to import

import android.app.Fragment;
Instead of

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

2- you can reverse it like ...
in your messagefragment remove import android.app.Fragment;

and import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;