# Android: how to load fragment into FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm starting with Android and in my project I'm using this [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar). Love it, works pretty well. The code of my application is almost identical on to the one he uses in the tutorial, the only different thing is that my `MainActivity` extends from `AppCompatActivity`.

Now what I'm trying to do is to load fragments in the `FrameLayout`:

```
<!-- This could be your fragment container, or something -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
    />
```

To do so I'm trying this piece of code, which I found googling for the answer of my issue:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
QrCodeFragment newFragment = new QrCodeFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.bottomBar, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

The line `transaction.replace(R.id.bottomBar, newFragment);` is complaining about the type of newFragment, which should be `android.app.Fragment`. My QrCode class: `public class QrCodeFragment extends Fragment`

As I'm starting with Android today I'm confused if I'm doing the right thing. **If I should really load fragments inside the `FrameLayout` and if so, what am I doing wrong that I can't load it**. I know it's the type of my fragment, but I don't know how to create it with the required type. I created it using `Android Studio > New > Fragment > Fragment (Blank)`

Thanks for any help

---

UPDATE:
I found the solution to my error in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496248/fragment-error-incompatible-types-required-android-app-fragment-but-found-acti) but even not having the error I still can't see the fragment.

Comment: From what I have understood, the container is what you inflate the fragment into. Meaning if you inflate it into a FrameLayout, it should still be fine - try it. If "complain" means compile error or crash, you should specify that

Comment: @LunarWatcher I actually found the issue and it's not getting me an error anymore.  I should just import android.app.Fragment; instead of import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; . Now the problem  is that it doesn't show me the fragment I just set to display

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First you have a mistake in your Fragment transaction line, according with your layout should be:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainer, newFragment); // not R.id.bottomBar
```

Second, you should use **supportFragmentManager** instead of **fragmentManager** to work with support fragments, so implement the following way:

```
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainer, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, it solved the issue. Actually, I just needed to put the right id (contentContainer).

Answer (score 2):

in my case i solve it by using

```
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

replace your

> FragmentTransaction

Answer (score 1):

```
            bottomNavigationView= findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
           bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {



               @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
               @Override
               public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                   Fragment temp =null;
                   switch (item.getItemId()) {
                       case R.id.library:
                            temp = new LibraryFragment();

                           
                           break;
                       case R.id.search:
                           temp = new SearchFragment();
                           break;
                       case R.id.profile:
                           temp = new UserprofileFragment();
                           break;
                       default:
                   }
                  

               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, temp).commit();


                        return true;
               }
           });


    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,new SearchFragment()).commit();
```