# Fragment in android, app not installing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Android studio is not able to run the code in my phone by building apk. When i run the code, apk does not get install on my phone but instead a blank white screen flashes and goes in the background. If i manually create the apk and put in my phone, then it is not able to intall. I dont get any install failure error but the installation process is not able to complete. I dont find such problem for any other applications which i made with android studio.

---

I want create two dynamic fragments in a single activity. I have a single container as relative layout. I have 2 buttons in my main activity as Red and Blue. When i click on Red button, Red fragment should be loaded. And when i click on Blue button, Blue `fragment` should be loaded in the container.

Code for the same is -

mainactivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();   
        Red r = new Red(); 
        transaction.add(R.id.relativeLayout, r);
        transaction.commit();
    }  
    public void redclick(View v)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Red r = new Red();

        transaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout, r);
        transaction.commit();
    }   
    public void blueclick(View v)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Blue b = new Blue(); 
        transaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout, b);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

red.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Red extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.red_layout, container, false);
    }

}
```

blue.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Blue extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blue_layout, container, false);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.deva.fragment.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="redclick"
        android:text="Red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.236"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.773"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12"
        android:onClick="blueclick"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="301dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.69">

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i m getting following exception in logcat -

```
02-21 10:31:58.454 25675-25675/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.deva.fragment, PID: 25675
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deva.fragment/com.example.deva.fragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                       at com.example.deva.fragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.deva.fragment.MainActivity@42965778 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                       at com.example.deva.fragment.Barcelona.onAttach(Barcelona.java:66)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1363)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1640)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1896)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3673)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:692)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                       at com.example.deva.fragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.deva.fragment">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle (app) -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deva.fragment"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

Comment: `R.id.relativeLayout` is it your framelayout id of something else?

Comment: it is the relative layout id @Hemant Parmar

Comment: fragment loads in container that should be in framelayout. try to change this.

Comment: changed it to frame layout, but still same results... @Hemant Parmar

Comment: Second, you should use supportFragmentManager instead of fragmentManager to work with support fragments, so implement the following way: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293887/5110595)

Comment: Add `activity_main.xml` to the question, please

Comment: i am using support fragment manager all over in the code.... Where m i missing it??@Hemant Parmar

Comment: @HemantParmar I don't think you read the question. The issue isn't the loading of the fragments. It's installing the app

Comment: share `activity_main.xml` and also share logcat.

Comment: @trex1999 i know but i read the code first, found something wrong thats why i told him first to correct this.

Comment: @HemantParmar Ok, well, if the app isn't running (because it isn't installing) there is also no logcat

Comment: @trex1999 Try disabling Instant Run? Or use an emulator?

Comment: guyz i have shared main_activity.xml and logcat..... i am getting an exception in logcat.... why is that so???

Comment: Put your build.gradle (app) and Manifest file

Comment: `com.example.deva.fragment.MainActivity` does your main activity exist in this package ?

Comment: @HemantParmar yes, the main activity is in the same package

Comment: Please post your build.gradle(app) file

Comment: I put build,gradle(app) file @Emre Aktürk

Comment: Nothing wrong with these files. I just copy-pasted files to my local project. Maybe we should check for red_layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error came from the `Barcelona` Fragment, not Red/Blue

```
MainActivity@42965778 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
   at com.example.deva.fragment.Barcelona.onAttach
```

I think the code you posted should work fine, but you either need to

1. Not use the Barcelona Fragment
2. Do what it says, and [**implement that interface**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener)
3. Remove the `throw new RuntimeException` part of that Fragment's `onAttach` method.

Comment: Well, your logcat says otherwise, so I'm not sure what to tell you

Comment: @trex1999 You could still create and implement that interface. It might just make the app work. If not, then you should definitely try to clean the project.